# Is it possible to set a hostname in a Kubernetes replication controller?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to set a static hostname in a Kubernetes replication controller. Docker supports it with some runtime flags, however, Kubernetes replication controllers don't appear to support it.
The environment: OS - CentOS 6.6
Approach to use sysctl to change the variable kernel.hostname does not work for a K8s replication controller. The host name is not changed.
Use:
sysctl kernel.hostname
to read the current hostname, and
sysctl kernel.hostname=NEW_HOSTNAME

Is it possible to set a hostname in a Kubernetes replication controller?

Answer (score 36):

In 1.7 you can set the hostname directly in the Deployment spec

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      hostname: myhostname
      containers:
        ...
```

**Old Answer**

Now that 1.2 has landed, you can set a static hostname in a Replication Controller or Deployment `spec` using the `pod.beta.kubernetes.io/hostname` annotation.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        pod.beta.kubernetes.io/hostname: myhostname
      labels:
        ...
```

Comment: Is it possible, that this is only working at deploymentsets and not at statefulsets?

Comment: Correct. Statefulsets control names in a different way

Comment: What will happen if I specify replicas to more than 1? Will all of them have the same hostname? Which is of course not OK

Comment: not sure actually. At a guess, I would assume that it would either:
* overwrite the DNS entry
* add another IP to the pool of IP addresses
* start a "round robin" dns response (that is, a different IP each lookup)

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't allows multiple-part hostnames (so no dots `.` allowed in the hostname). Also, this affects the system hostname but not kubernetes name resolution, which continues to use the usual DNS naming scheme for pods and services.

Answer (score 6):

Kubernetes (currently) treats pods as cattle, not pets, so it's undesirable to specify hostnames of the individual pods. There is a lengthy discussion in the [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4825) on the needs of (re-)using hostnames and how to solve that. It seems that the [nominal services](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18016) (a.k.a. PetSets), which is yet to be implemented, may help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This feature (hostnames) is coming in kubernetes v1.2