# Setting the correct hostname in Kubernetes/Nginx for the client

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, microservices

I'm using a dockerized microservice architecture running on Kubernetes with Nginx, and am encountering an issue with hostnames. How do you correctly add the hostname to Kubernetes (or perhaps Nginx too)?

The problem: When microservice A called `admin` tries to talk to microservice B called `session`, `admin` logs the following error and `session` is not reached:

```
{ Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's 
altnames: Host: session. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.example.com, example.com
at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:225:17)
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:27)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:638:8)
  reason: 'Host: session. is not in the cert\'s altnames: 
DNS:*.example.com, example.com',
  host: 'session',
  cert:
   { subject: { OU: 'Domain Control Validated', CN: 
'*.example.com' },
     issuer: ...
```

In response to this error, I tried to update the hostname in the kubernetes config yaml file unsuccessfully (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609572/is-it-possible-to-set-a-hostname-in-a-kubernetes-replication-controller)). See the added `hostname` below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: session
  namespace: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: session
      component: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: session
        component: demo
    spec:
      hostname: session.example.com . ----> added host name here
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-secret 
      containers:
      - name: session
       ...
```

However, when I try to apply this updated config file in Kubernetes, an error emerges that I cannot use a period.  If I cannot use a period, and the hostname is `*.example.com` (i.e. `session.example.com`), where/how should the hostname be updated.

```
The Deployment "session" is invalid: spec.template.spec.hostname: 
Invalid value: "session.example.com": a DNS-1123 label must 
consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and 
end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex 
used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

Meanwhile, the server name in the nginx config file is indeed updated with `session.example.com`.

```
upstream session {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  keepalive 32;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name "session.example.com";  ---> updated for hostname 

  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nginx/certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/key.pem;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://session/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
  }
}


server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name "session.example.com";    ---> updated for hostname 

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

How do you suggest fixing this? My goal is for `admin` to successfully communicate with `session`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kubernetes own dns.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

So you can access your pod using pod dns;

> When enabled, pods are assigned a DNS A record in the form of
>
> **“pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local”**

With service you can use

> **my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local**